# SendGrid Azure Issue

Tags: node.js, azure, sendgrid

I'm trying to send an email with my Node JS app on Azure and get this error:

```
TypeError: sendgrid.Email is not a constructor
```

Here is my code. I used the documentation from Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/store-sendgrid-nodejs-how-to-send-email).

```
var sendgrid = require('sendgrid')('SendGrid User ID', 'SendGrid password');
function createEmail() {
    console.log('CREATE EMAIL');

    var emailToSend = new sendgrid.Email({
        to: example@example.com,
        from: 'example@example.com',
        subject: 'Subject',
        text: 'some text';
    });

    sendEmail(emailToSend);
}

function sendEmail(email) {
    console.log('SEND EMAIL');
    sendgrid.send(email, function (err, json) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/269 -- it seems like SendGrid Node support has had breaking changes made to it since the MSDN article that you linked was written.  The GitHub thread I linked has a link to an updated code example: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v3_Mail/nodejs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @David Tansey mentioned, the SendGrid team added a breaking change to support the v3 Web API since [v3.0.0](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300---2016-06-13). [Here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs#quick-start) is a working code example with the latest version (v5.1.2).

```
var helper = require('sendgrid').mail;
var fromEmail = new helper.Email('test@example.com');
var toEmail = new helper.Email('test@example.com');
var subject = 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun';
var content = new helper.Content('text/plain', 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js');
var mail = new helper.Mail(fromEmail, subject, toEmail, content);

var sg = require('sendgrid')(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
var request = sg.emptyRequest({
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/v3/mail/send',
  body: mail.toJSON()
});

sg.API(request, function (error, response) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('Error response received');
  }
  console.log(response.statusCode);
  console.log(response.body);
  console.log(response.headers);
});
```

However, if you want your provided code run smoothly, you'll need to revert the version to 2.0.0.